# How to change the position of the page number in the first page of every chapter of a book?

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering

I am using the book.cls and I want that the page number of the first page (only the first page) of every chapter be at the bottom and on the right. And page numbering of the other pages remain intact.

Here is my .tex file:
‎

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,‎twoside]{book}‎‎
‎\usepackage{lipsum}‎‎‎‎
‎\usepackage{fancybox,‎fancyhdr}‎
‎\pagestyle{fancy}‎
‎\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%‎
        ‎\markboth{#1}{}}‎
‎\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{%‎
        ‎\markright{\thesection\ #1}}‎
‎\fancyhf{} 
‎\fancyhead[LE]{\small\leftmark‎}‎
‎\fancyhead[RO]{\small\rightmark‎}‎
‎\fancyhead[RE,LO]{\textbf{\thepage}}‎
‎\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}‎
‎\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%‎
‎\markboth{\thechapter\ #1}{}}‎
‎\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\ ‎#1}}‎‎‎
‎\begin{document}‎‎
‎\chapter{Chapter‎ ‎one}‎‎
‎\section{Section‎ ‎one‎‎}‎‎
‎\lipsum[1-‎10‎‎‎]‎‎
‎\end{document}‎‎
```

How can I do this?

Comment: I think that probably this question would not have been answered if the fancyhdr manual have been carefully read.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `titlesec` package's `\assignpagestyle` to set the page style for `\chapter`. Something like this.

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\newpagestyle{chapterpage}{\setfoot{}{}{\thepage}}
\assignpagestyle\chapter{chapterpage}
```

**Edit**: Now that you've added a sample, I know that you're using `fancyhdr` so the solution is simple:

```
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
    \fancyhead{}
    \fancyfoot[R]{\textbf{\thepage}}
}
```

Comment: @TH: Thanks, but your solution doesn't work. In fact, the result is terrible. Because your code typesets "1 Chapter One" in the footer (and also in the header) as well.

Comment: @Malek: It worked just fine. You neglected to mention what you were actually doing. Now that you've done so, I've edited my answer to provide a simple solution.

Comment: @TH: Thanks very much for your reply. Now it is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 3):

I assume that you want the first page of evey chapter to have the same layout of the other pages, correct?
And probably you are using `fancyhdr`, isn't it?

If so, maybe [this](http://texblog.net/latex-archive/layout/page-style-plain-fancy/) can help you. Otherwise, you can redefine the layout of `plain` (the style invoked for every `\chapter` command) pages like this:

```
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage} % except the right
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}}
```

taken from page 8 of [fancyhdr user manual](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.pdf).

Comment: "I assume that you want the first page of evey chapter to have the same layout of the other pages, correct?" No! I just want the number of first page of every chapter (only this page) be at the bottom and on the right. Please see my code above.

Comment: I answered your question when there wasn't a line of example code, that's the reason of my assumptions. Again, the answer to your question is in page 8 of the fancyhdr user manual. Probably you should have read the documentation instead of posting the question.

Comment: I had to push the two last lines (\renewcommand{...}) to before the \fancyfoot to make it work in my case. My intention was to have the first page of a chapter numbered in the center of the bottom footer. However, by default I was getting the header bar without any text on the top of the page. This header was removed by shifting the last two lines to before the \fancyfoot[..]{...}.

Comment: This helped me too. Thank you.