# chapter heading page numbers

Tags: lyx, page-numbering, header-footer

I know this has been covered but I can't get any solutions that I've seen to work.
Page numbers for my thesis are upper right but the first page of each chapter should have it bottom center.
I tried using ERT (in LYX) `\thispagestyle{plain}` and also loading `\usepackage{sectsty}` and then using `\chapterfont{\pagestyle{plain}}` after the chapter heading.

I looked at [Modifying plain page style](http://texblog.net/latex-archive/layout/page-style-plain-fancy/) and questions on
[changing position of page number on the first page of every chapter of a book](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4332/how-to-change-the-position-of-the-page-number-in-the-first-page-of-every-chapter)
and [page number position](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10043/page-number-position)

I'm using the class from [CU Boulder](http://sites.google.com/site/nathanandrewmiller/cuboulderthesisusinglyx)

EDIT: I don't go to CU but I am trying to use the class for my thesis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did get

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}  % Delete current setting for header and footer

\fancypagestyle{main}{% page style for normal pages
  \fancyhfoffset[R]{0.5in}
  \fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{
  \fancyhfoffset[R]{0.25in}
  \fancyhead{}  % Get rid of headers and footers on plain pages...
  \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}  % ...and of the lines
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
}

\fancypagestyle{empty}{
  \fancyhead{}  % Get rid of headers and footers on empty pages...
  \fancyfoot{}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}  % ...and of the lines
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
}
```

to work with `\pagestyle{main}` as `ERT` before any main text and `\thispagestyle{plain}` as `ERT` after each chapter heading.

thanks [meho_r](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=12891&start=10)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Koma-Script, you can use the `scrpage2` package, and then define your own styles `scrheadings` and `scrplain` (see the Koma-Script manual). You can then assign them to all pages but the chapter pages, or to the chapter pages specifically:

```
\renewcommand*{\chapterpagestyle}{scrplain}
```

Comment: I don't believe I'm using Koma-Script....how do I tell? Is it included in .cls?  I'm using LyX so I've missed some of that stuff.

Comment: Koma-Script provides several classes to replace the standard LaTeX classes --- `scrbook` replaces `book`, `scrartcl` replaces `article`, etc. These classes are generally more configurable than the traditional LaTeX classes. See http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/scrguien.pdf for documentation.