# Change page number position in the middle of a document

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering, front-matter

I'm creating a large document. My document contains three parts : frontmatter, main, backmatter.
For frontmatter I have to place page number centering, for main I have to place page number flushright, and for backmatter I have to place page number centering.

So confusing about it.
Anyone could help me please ?
Can I use this : [How to change the position of the page number in the first page of every chapter of a book?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4332/how-to-change-the-position-of-the-page-number-in-the-first-page-of-every-chapter)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) You don't have to sign with your name since it automatically appears in the lower right corner of your post.

Comment: Yes, you could use the solution of the Link you posted. There are others for what you'd like to achieve, but the one you Linked to is the cleanest one in my opinion.

Comment: it works well in latex (miktex,texmaker,windows), but not in lyx, I'm looking for lyx ? :(

Comment: If the answer of Keks Dose was helpful, please upvote it. If not, please add more details to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using a KOMA-Script class, you get the documentation typing `texdoc komascript` into a console-window.

I did not test it myself, but KOMA-Script offers the command `\KOMAoption{}` . I guess you could change the settings of the pagenumber for the next page at any place in the document.

Besides that, KOMA-Script offers different "styles" for front-, main- and backmatter.

Comment: it works well in latex (miktex,texmaker,windows), but not in lyx, I'm looking for lyx ? :(